# How to observer child vue finish render

Tags: vuejs2

I am working on a **chat tool** using vue single file components.I am facing a problem,root .vue has child .vue and grandchild .vue, I want to **observer children's rendering,to get the root div's height,to change scrollbar position**,
i used the $nextTick() http://rc.vuejs.org/api/#vm-nextTick,but it cant observer children's render,so ,is there any way can I try? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use parent child communication of vue to get to know when you child has rendered. Vue provided following [event interface](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-on-with-Custom-Events):

- Listen to an event using $on(eventName)
- Trigger an event using
  $emit(eventName)

A parent component can listen to the events emitted from a child component using v-on directly in the template where the child component is used.

So you can emit a event in your child component's [lifecycle hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted) like following:

```
mounted () {
  this.$emit('childRendered')
}
```

In parent component, you can listen to this event or create a method, like following:

```
this.$on('childRendered', function () {
  // change scrollbar position
})
```

An example of parent child communication: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/michaelmilo/4kyzkgLu/2/)

Comment: but it not a click event.It changes when data change,so $on and $emit is useless

Comment: @alineLily If it is a data change: I see two options; One: You can use [updated](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) life cycle hook which is called after a data change causes the virtual DOM to be re-rendered and patched. Two: you can set up  [watchers](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) which will watch for data change.

Answer (score 0):

This is just for everyone to easily see the workaround that was mentioned by Saurabh in his comment to his answer. I also used the [updated](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated) lifecycle to wait for the DOM to finish rendering and patching before manipulating it again.

Since `updated` does not guarantee that all child components have also been re-rendered, use vm.$nextTick inside of updated.

```
updated: function () {
  this.$nextTick(function () {
    // Code that will run only after the
    // entire view has been re-rendered
  })
}
```